# Unexplainable behavior of .push_back for a vector<char> in functions

Tags: vector, visual-c++

I am quite new to C++ and during solving a Codewars Kata I faced following problem.
I want to define a Variable of type std::vector with the name tmp2 in a function.
Add a char via push_back and return the value.

When I set a breakpoint at return(tmp2) and debug the code (MSVS2022), the debugger shows tmp2 as empty.

If I do the same operation in a void function the debugger shows tmp with 'c' as content

Here is my code:

```
#include <vector>
//turn on debugger 
//set a breakpoint at return(tmp2) in function test2() and inspect tmp2

void test()
{
    std::vector<char> tmp;
    tmp.push_back('c'); //tmp holds 'c' 
}

std::vector<char> test2()
{
    std::vector<char> tmp2;
    tmp2.push_back('c');
    return(tmp2);//tmp2 does not contain 'c'
}



int main()
{
    test();
    std::vector<char> x = test2();
}
```

Could someone please tell me, where I am wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Regs
Marcus

I have tried to clean my project.
But I cannot find out where I am wrong.
An explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: How do you know that the `push_back` has no effect on `tmp2`? Is there an effect on `c` in `main`?

Comment: The returned vector *does* contain `c` but the local vector (`tmp2`) can be optimized away. Look up "return value optimization" and "copy elision".

Comment: The vector returned by `test2()` does too [contain `c`](https://godbolt.org/z/ePhsq1fnc). Your example does not reproduce the problem you claim you have. For further assistance, prepare a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for the answers.
I think the "return value optimization" is the "problem".
@Igor:
Yes you are right, in main x contains the value 'c'.
My problem was, that I could not see 'c' in tmp2 when I was in Debug Mode and the debugger stopped at return(tmp2) in function test2.